# How to add color and asterisk per plot using seaborn pairgird and seaborn barplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to plot 3 horizontal bar plots, with the labels as the y axis the the data as the x axis, and I want each plot to be a different color, and have some type of annotation such as an asterisk which depends on the signficiance denoted by a column in the data, for example:

```
dat = pd.DataFrame({
    'Labels':['v1','v2','c1','c2'],
    'Ave': [.2, .3, .5, .9],
    'SD': [0.02, 0.1, 0.04, 0.06],
    'Tot': [3, 4, 6, 8],
    'Sig': [0.05, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.05]
})

sns.set_style('white')

g = sns.PairGrid(dat, x_vars=['Ave', 'SD', 'Tot'], y_vars=['Labels'])
g.map(sns.barplot)
```

will get me something like this:

[image]

How do I get each plot, "Ave" "SD" and "ToT" to be their own color ? and how could I add annotations to denote significance, given by the "Sig" column ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get close by reshaping your data to a long (tidy) format and use `factorplot`.

Reshaping:

```
dat = (
  pandas.DataFrame({
      'Labels':['v1','v2','c1','c2'],
      'Ave': [.2, .3, .5, .9],
      'SD': [0.02, 0.1, 0.04, 0.06],
      'Tot': [3, 4, 6, 8],
      'Sig': [0.05, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.05]
  }).set_index('Labels')
    .unstack()
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={
      'level_0': 'stat',
      0: 'result'
  })
)

print(dat.head(8))

  stat Labels  result
0  Ave     v1    0.20
1  Ave     v2    0.30
2  Ave     c1    0.50
3  Ave     c2    0.90
4   SD     v1    0.02
5   SD     v2    0.10
6   SD     c1    0.04
7   SD     c2    0.06
```

And factorplot:

```
seaborn.factorplot('result', 'Labels', data=dat,
                   kind='bar', sharex=False,
                   hue='stat', hue_order=stats,
                   col='stat', col_order=stats)
```

[image]

The problem is that the bars are offset since using `hue` tells seaborn to make room for different categories at each y-position.

In the next release, you'll be able to say `dodge=False` to avoid this offset.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't figured out how to get this done with seaborn but with matplotlib this will work

```
import pandas as pd

dat = pd.DataFrame({
    'Labels':['v1','v2','c1','c2'],
    'Ave': [.2, .3, .5, .9],
    'SD': [0.02, 0.1, 0.04, 0.06],
    'Tot': [3, 4, 6, 8],
    'Sig':[0.05, 0.005, 0.0001, 0.05],
    'Sig_mask': [1,2,3,1],
})   

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()

# multiple plots 
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(131)

# horizontal bar plot and set color
ax1.barh(dat.index.values, dat['SD'], color='r', align='center')

# SET SPINES VISIBLE
ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['top'].set_visible(False)

# SET X, Y LABELS
ax1.set(yticks=dat.index.values, yticklabels=dat.Labels.values)
ax1.set(xlabel='SD')

# ADD SIG NOTATION
for idx, val in enumerate(dat.SD.values):
    ax1.text(x=val+.003, y=idx, s='*'*dat.Sig_mask[idx], va='center')

# ADD SECOND PLOT
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(132)
# everything else much in the same manner, change color and data column


# ADD THIRD PLOT
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(133)
# same as above
```